# Failing Recaptcha V3

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

I'm looking for assistance on creating a failed test case for Google reCAPTCHA v3. I've attempted to do so using Selenium Python automation, but it seems to be bypassing the reCAPTCHA entirely. Shouldn't reCAPTCHA detect automation as a bot? How can I properly test it to ensure that the test fails? Is reCAPTCHA version 3 not as effective as expected?

Comment: what score(s) are you getting from reCaptcha?  On how many different pages are you placing it?